# What does 'jQuery.each(lines, function(lineNo, line)' do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a beginner in jquery and ajax. While i was going through some example online, i came across the following piece of code and wondered what exactly it does.

```
    lines = newLine.split('#');

 jQuery.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {                    
                        eval("linedata = " + line);             
                        data.push(linedata);

                    });
```

I'm not a programmer, but just trying to understand its functionality. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: `eval`? Wherever you got this, throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

The each function iterates over an array which is supplied as the first parameter.  During each iteration the index and element are passed into a function that is performed.  The function is passed as the second parameter to the `each` function.

Read more on the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

In the example you have provided a string `newLine` is split into an array using `#` as the delimiter.

The `each` function then iterates over the newly created array, assigning the value of each element to a variable linedata and pushes linedata onto another array.

This could be more easily achieved with the following, since the call to eval is unnecessary:

```
 jQuery.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {                                
     data.push(line);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I pretended, for a moment, that I was a new programmer. This is how you should go about looking into things from here on out:

1.) Ok, I don't know what this first line is doing. It's splitting something (based on the `split` word). Hmmm let's Google for "split javascript". [This is the first thing that comes up.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) From here, you may be wondering what a String is, so you would search for that as well).

2.) Ok so now I know that splitting a String gives me an array (again you probably looked this up by this step) of the `newLine` substrings that were separated by the `#` character. Cool. So let's look into what `jQuery.each` does. I google "jQuery.each" and [this is the first thing that comes up](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Awesome! Now you understand what a `String` is, an `Array`, the `split` function from `String` as well as what `jQuery.each` is. :D

EDIT: As you move forward, you'll realize that W3C is generally an inferior source of information. I simply linked to it since it was literally the first thing that came up when I Googled "split javascript". Overall it does the job for giving you a good overview of certain things when you're learning them for the first time.